# Can't connect to MariaDB with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

Today, I installed MariaDB on my Debian 11 Server. Now I want to connect with MySQL Workbench, but it doesn't work. I also created a new user named "Simone" and if I try to connect with my SSH connection with `mysql -h 192.168.1.45 -u simone -p` It works but when I try to connect with Workbench it gives me an Error:

[image: Workbench Error Picture]

Comment: try workbench 5.7 instead of 8, but you can only install 1 of them at  a time

Comment: Mariadb is not fully compatible with mysql, therefore mysql workbench will bump into problems with mariadb.

Comment: Why does the error dialog say _"localhost"_?

Answer (score 4):

*MySQL* Workbench is not compatible with newer versions of MariaDB. You have either to use [MariaDB Workbench](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/database-workbench/) or a multi-vendor tool such as [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

The fact that you can use the `mysql` command line tool is that historically the MariaDB packages install their client binary under that name in order to keep shell scripts etc. working.

Comment: Do you have a reference URL for this incompatibility please? I can't find any info on this change on the web

Comment: This is not specific to Workbench; the APIs have diverged over time https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=mysql+mariadb+compatibility

Answer (score -1):

The access is still operative.
You only need to edit conf files from mariadb server.
(In debian distros):

```
 cd /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
 sudo nano 50-server.cnf
```

Comment bind-address line to allow connection from every host and restart the service:

```
sudo service mariadb restart
```

Voila!